# angularjs formly submit bug in safari & IE 11

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angular-formly

Submit is getting triggered on Enter key press even when submit button is in disabled state (disabled="disabled")

This happens only when form has one input field.

In Safari 9x and IE 11, submit action is getting triggered on Enter key press.  In chrome it works fine.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/l9UURtqV43JBoTqBEJ5J?p=preview

Comment: Check this out... https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly/issues/676

Answer (score 1):

Use `type="button"` and ng-click for form submission.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="vm.doSubmit()">Click me</button>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/8rB1ZmFjvKd4fuBLsvxM?p=preview

Comment: I need Enter key option to submit the form when it is valid(ie. when first name value is > 3 character in length)